# issue accessing elements of hash in perl

Tags: perl

I have the below hash:

```
my %releaseMap = {"rel1.2.3" => {
                                    "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
                                    "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                                },

                  "rel2.4" =>   {
                                    "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
                                    "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                                }
                 };
```

I want to get the values rel1.2.3 and rel2.4 in the variable $rel, I want to get the values lnx86 and lnppc in $port and I want to get the value DEV in $branch.

I am new to the Hash concept in perl, I am not able to figure out how this can be done.

Can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: If you really have `my %releaseMap = { ... };`, you have a hash with a single element, whose key is something like `HASH(0xFFFFFFFF)` and whose value is undef. The code also warns. Did you mean `my %releaseMap = ( ... );`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you really have

```
my %releaseMap = ("rel1.2.3" => {
                                    "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
                                    "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                                },

                  "rel2.4" =>   {
                                    "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
                                    "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                                }
                 );
```

You can use

```
for my $rel_id (keys(%releaseMap)) {
   my $rel = $releaseMap{$rel_id};

   my $ports    = $rel->{supporedPorts};
   my $branches = $rel->{branch};

   say "[$rel_id] ports = @$ports; branches = @$branches";
}
```

Docs:

- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Answer (score 2):

A hash is initialised from a list:

```
my %hash = ( key => value, ... );
```

A hash **reference** is initialised using the anonymous hash constructor:

```
my $hash_ref = { key => value, ... };
```

You are initialising your hash with an anonymous hash constructor. This does not work as you expect it. You end up with a hash containing a single key (which is the stringification of the anonymous hash reference:

```
my %hash = { key => value, ... };
```

If you change your code to this:

```
my %releaseMap = ("rel1.2.3" => {
                                    "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
                                    "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                                },

                  "rel2.4" =>   {
                                    "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
                                    "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                                }
                 );
```

Then things get easier. You can start with:

```
foreach my $key (keys %releaseMap) {
  say $key;
}
```

Also, add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code. They will catch a lot of problems for you.

Comment: Thanks all for the response. It really helped. I used the below code:

Comment: my %releaseMap = ("rel1.2.3" => {
                                    "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86"],
                                    "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                                },

                  "rel2.4" =>   {
                                    "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
                                    "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                                }
                 );

Comment: );
foreach my $release (keys (%releaseMap)) {
    my $rel = $releaseMap{$release};
    my $port    = $rel->{supporedPorts};
    my $branch = $rel->{branch};
    print "$release\n port = @$port\n branch = $branch\n";
}

and it is giving me the below output:

rel2.4
 port = lnx86 lnppc
 branch = ISR
rel1.2.3
 port = lnx86
 branch = ISR

Comment: I have one more question please. Can I get the values of rel1.2.3 and rel2.4 as rel123 and rel24 using the above code in a variable say $release1

is there a way to do this ? Please help.

Comment: @PaulIT: If someone has answered your original question, then you should accept their answer. If you now have additional questions, then you should ask those separately.