# Issue using hash in perl

Tags: perl

I have the below code:

```
my %releaseMap = {"rel1.2.3" => {
                                "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86"],
                                "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                            },

              "rel2.4" =>   {
                                "supporedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
                                "branch"        => ["DEV"],
                            }
             };

sub readlnk
{

    foreach my $release (keys %releaseMap) {
        my $rel = $releaseMap{$release};

        my $port = $rel->{supportedPorts};
        my $branch = $rel->{branch};

        $abc = readlink "/home/test1/test2/test3/rel1.2.3/DEV/lnx86/64/builds/buildComplete";
        $bcd = readlink "/home/test1/test2/test3/rel2.4/DEV/lnx86/64/builds/buildComplete";
        $cde = readlink "/home/test1/test2/test3/rel2.4/DEV/lnppc/64/builds/buildComplete";

    }
}
```

The output of print "$release\n port = @$port[0]\n branch = $branch\n"; is

```
rel1.2.3
 port = lnx86
 branch = DEV
rel2.4
 port = lnx86
 branch = DEV
```

I want to remove the hardcoding I have done in the readlink lines. I want that each readlink line should take the appropriate release, branch and port from the foreach loop that I wrote in my script and replace with the hardcoding. For instance, in the first readlink line $release should replace rel1.2.3 and in the second readlink line $release should replace rel2.4 and same for branch and port.

Can someone please assist me regarding this. Thanks

Comment: `%hash = (...)`, but `$hash_ref = { ... }`.

Comment: In what way is this not a duplicate of [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62145933/issue-accessing-elements-of-hash-in-perl)? And why are you still making the `%hash = { ... }` error that you were told about in the answers to that question?

Comment: I've fixed the indentation in your code (and added what looks like a missing closing brace). You are most welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Careful indentation is a valuable tool for understanding code and if you're asking a large group of people to read and understand your code, it's only polite to make it as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perl, when you assign to a `%hash` you are supposed to assign a `(list, ...)` (that's surrounded with parentheses).  When you use `{ }` instead of `( )`, you're actually specifying a "hash reference," which is a single element instead of an even-numbered list.

Sometimes you want a hash reference, such as when you're assigning to a `$scalar` variable, or embedding hashes inside of lists or hashes.

But if you're assigning to a `%hash`, the outside braces should be `(` and `)` -- and not `{` and `}`.

Depending on your Perl version and whether you use strict & warnings, your Perl program could warn and/or fail if you try to assign an odd-numbered list to a `%hash`.  So consider placing the lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the top of your script, and see if they point out that your code is incorrect (specifically, the part where your code is assigning values to `%releaseMap`).

---

Also, consider using the excellent Data::Dumper module to verify that your variables really hold what you think they're holding.

So right after you set `%releaseMap`, add in these two lines of code to see if your assignment did what you thought it did:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%releaseMap;
```

(I placed a `\` before `%releaseMap` to pass in a reference to the `Dumper()` function.  `Dumper()` handles hash references better than hashes.)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I implemented the points you mentioned and got the below result after doing

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%releaseMap;

Comment: $VAR1 = {
          'rel1.2.3' => {
                          'supporedPorts' => [
                                               'lnx86'
                                             ],
                          'branch' => 'DEV'
                        },
          'rel2.4' => {
                        'supporedPorts' => [
                                             'lnx86',
                                             'lnppc'
                                           ],
                        'branch' => 'DEV'
                      }
        };

Comment: Can you also please let me know how I can get rid of the hardcodings like I mentioned in my above question. Thanks

Comment: @PaulIT: Please don't dump code in comments. It is unreadable. Instead, please edit your question to add further information.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please read carefully the [answers to the very similar question you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62145933/issue-accessing-elements-of-hash-in-perl). Your code is still making the mistake of assigning a hash reference to a hash.

```
my %hash = { ... };
```

Where you should either assign a list to a hash:

```
my %hash = ( ... );
```

Or assign a hash reference to a scalar variable.

```
my $hash_ref = { ... };
```

You seem to be asking about inserting the values of a variable in a string. Perl makes this very easy. If you have a double-quoted string then simply mentioning a variable in that string will substitute the current value of that variable. This code demonstrates that:

```
my $rel = 'rel1.2.3';
my $port = 'lnx86';
my $branch = 'DEV';

my $str = "/home/test1/test2/test3/$rel/$branch/$port/64/builds/buildComplete";

print $str;
```

**Update:** I think you want something like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %releaseMap = (
  "rel1.2.3" => {
    "supportedPorts" => ["lnx86"],
    "branch"         => ["DEV"],
  },

  "rel2.4" =>   {
    "supportedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
    "branch"         => ["DEV"],
  }
);

foreach my $release (keys %releaseMap) {
  my $rel = $releaseMap{$release};

  for my $port (@{$rel->{supportedPorts}}) {
    for my $branch (@{$rel->{branch}}) {
      my $str = "/home/test1/test2/test3/$release/$branch/$port/64/builds/buildComplete";
      say $str;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I used () instead of {} now.

$release contains both rel1.2.3 and rel2.4 values so when I print $str it prints the value of  buildComplete link for both rel1.2.3 and rel2.4 
but what I need is that wherever in my code there is rel1.2.3 it should be replaced by $release and same for rel2.4

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I tried *to wrap my head around* of your question and hope that following code reflects what you looking for

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %releaseMap = (
            "rel1.2.3" => {
                            "supportedPorts" => ["lnx86"],
                            "branches"       => ["DEV"],
                        },

            "rel2.4" =>   {
                            "supportedPorts" => ["lnx86", "lnppc"],
                            "branches"       => ["DEV"],
                        }
             );

readlnk($_) for keys %releaseMap;

sub readlnk {
    my $release = shift;

    my $base_dir  = '/home/test1/test2/test3';
    my $build_dir = '64/builds/buildComplete';

    my $ports    = $releaseMap{$release}{supportedPorts};
    my $branches = $releaseMap{$release}{branches};

    for my $port ( @$ports ) {
        for my $branch ( @$branches ) {
            #my $link = readlink "$base_dir/$release/$branch/$port/$build_dir";
            my $link = "$base_dir/$release/$branch/$port/$build_dir";
            say "$release\n port = $port\n branch = $branch\n link = $link";
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
rel2.4
 port = lnx86
 branch = DEV
 link = /home/test1/test2/test3/rel2.4/DEV/lnx86/64/builds/buildComplete
rel2.4
 port = lnppc
 branch = DEV
 link = /home/test1/test2/test3/rel2.4/DEV/lnppc/64/builds/buildComplete
rel1.2.3
 port = lnx86
 branch = DEV
 link = /home/test1/test2/test3/rel1.2.3/DEV/lnx86/64/builds/buildComplete
```

NOTE: `readlink` is commented out in this sample code (it require to recreated build directory structure which I do not have)